# Datetime comparison returning wrong results in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, percona

I've come across an unusual issue when the following MySQL query is return inconsistent results and I'm trying to figure out why. I've already found a working query, but I would like to understand why the query didn't work as expected:

```
SELECT id, ExpiryDate
FROM sites
WHERE ExpiryDate >= '2018-12-24 00:00:00' 
  AND ExpiryDate <= '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
```

These are the following tests I ran for comparison:

- MySQL via shell = correct results
- MySQL Workbench = correct results
- DBeaver = incorrect results
- PHPStorm SQL console = incorrect results
- PHP 7.0 script = incorrect results

The results expected would obviously be records where the ExpiryDate is between the two dates provided. However, in the instances where the results returned incorrect, we were getting records with dates before the 24th December, 2018.

I changed the query to the below which works:

```
SELECT id, ExpiryDate
FROM sites
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ExpiryDate) 
   BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-12-24 00:00:00') 
   AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-01-01 00:00:00')
```

I'm quite interested in understanding why the first query returned incorrect results? Is this a PHP bug, MySQL bug or something I'm doing wrong? I'm running MySQL 5.6 and PHP 7.0. PHP is running via mysqli extension. I've already confirmed this issue on multiple machines and confirmed all running the same database data. The ExpiryDate field is a datetime field.

Comment: Can you show us the **true** incorrect results  ?

Comment: This could be a time zone issue. I suggest you edit the question and provide: 1) The column type 2) Sample data that illustrates the issue

Comment: @DanielE. here you go: 40, 2018-11-30 00:00:00

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález The sample data is litterally just primary IDs and a datetime field. Interestingly enough, the problem only occurs with ranges which cross over a year.

Comment: @David edit your question with the sample data please.

Comment: If you're running that exact query and column is `DATETIME` them I'm clueless, sorry.